# Getting Segmentation Fault in kotlinc command

Tags: kotlin, segmentation-fault

I recently installed Kotlin on Linux Mint, but I have been getting segmentation fault since the start. Even on simple programs like "Hello World" resulted in segfault.

I have tried my best but nothing seems to help. I have removed and installed it again without success. Even `kotlinc` produces a segmentation fault and `kotlinc -help` too.

I installed it using the following snap command:

`sudo snap install --classic kotlin`

[image: Snapshot of terminal]

Please help me resolve this error. Sorry if it's trivial as I am new to Kotlin and there were no similar threads available on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I have installed sdkman and followed the instruction related with it to install kotlin this way and it worked.

`curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash`

`source "/home/luctivud/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`

`sdk install kotlin`

Don't know why installing this way works.